# In the USA, is it still legal to create a website to connect sex providers with clients?

Tags: united-states, internet

A few years ago I believe this was outlawed? Can anyone confirm?

Comment: You might be thinking of [FOSTA-SESTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSTA-SESTA), an anti-trafficking law passed in 2018 following the [prosecution of the operators of Backpage.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpage#Federal_prosecution).  It's not inherently illegal, but you would have to ensure that your site does not in any way assist, promote, support, or facilitate human trafficking.  That's a difficult standard to meet.

Comment: FOSTA-SESTA also revoked the [Section 230 safe harbor](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230) as applied to trafficking cases.  So you as the site operator can't avail yourself of the defense that "I just post the ads that the providers send in, how they operate is nothing to do with me".  In short, it's not something you'd want to attempt without some very extensive (and expensive) legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still legal, if you want to book an appointment, you can [do it online](https://mustangranchbrothel.com/). It is legal in that county. Analogously, marijuana is legal in Colorado and fully illegal in adjacent Kansas, and stores in Colorado can advertise online ([example](https://maggiesfarmmarijuana.com/locations/colorado-springs-north/)), even though some customers might come from neighboring not-legal state.

Commercial speech is protected under the First Amendment, though not as strongly as political speech. The FCC has (had) extra powers to regulate content broadcast on the airways, which explains some features for pharmaceutical ads (asking your doctor if X is "right for you" when they don't even say what X does). Those regulations do not apply to online commerce.

Of course, if you run a brothel in a jurisdiction where prostitution is illegal, you can be prosecuted for all sorts of things.

Comment: Why did craigslist remove their de factor section connecting sex providers with clients then?

Comment: If this is really your question, you should edit the original question and ask this instead of what you asked.  If this is a follow-up, then a new question is probably your best bet.

Comment: It isn't legal if you are conspiring in some other crime in a way not exempted under Section 230.

Comment: Craigslist is free to ban whatever it wants – that is not directly a case of outlawing certain kinds of advertising. Facebook bans various forms of speech which are perfectly legal. Seems to me you have a completely different question in mind.